# How to do UDP hole punching in Qt?

Tags: qt, networking, udp, nat, hole-punching

I have a server on Internet that can send and receive datagrams.

What should I do on the client side in order to punch a hole so that I can receive datagrams from the server?

Comment: Just so you know, this is really, *really* complicated.

Comment: Just to make sure: You want to punch a hole between two instances of the same program (running on different clients) by using your server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have to design your client in following way
1. Client Should be able to connect to Server and request the IP and Port of other client.
2. Once each client gets Ip port of each other should start onnection with each other.
folow the article in the given link.
http://www.brynosaurus.com/pub/net/p2pnat/